# Get height of row where the cells have WrapText set

Tags: c#, excel, openxml, measurestring

I am trying to compute the height of the row I'm inserting into my excel sheet. The row's cells are formatted with `WrapText=true`, so the height of the row is not fixed.
Accessing row.Height will return null.

I was thinking of using something similar to `Graphics.MeasureString` where I also specify the width constraint in order to retrieve the height.

Didn't find any relevant info online. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `Row.Height` works for me... Either way, if you select any cell in the row and use `Activecell.Height`, doesn't it return the height for you??

Comment: `Row.Height` doesn't seem to work on rows that has cells with "warp text". On the other hand, `ActiveCell` is of type `StringValue` and doesn't have a `Height` property..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my post here using Graphics.MeasureString.  It works very well.

[Autofit Row Height of Merged Cell in EPPlus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41639278/autofit-row-height-of-merged-cell-in-epplus/43942515#43942515)