# Getting the number of lines spanned by wrapped text

Tags: c#, word-wrap

I would like to count the number of lines a particular string will occupy when wrapped in a container with a fixed width, and using a given font...

My original problem was [getting the height of a row in excel with wrapped text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25268234/get-height-of-row-where-the-cells-have-wraptext-set). I've given up on a straightforward solution so I would like to use an algorithm for determining the number of lines occupied (and hence the height of the row).

I realize I can develop my own algorithm making use of `Graphics.MeasureString`, but I was wondering if there is an already developed clean solution that won't make me go through this mess.

Comment: I doubt it. But since `Graphics.MeasureString` lets you pass in the width of the container: _To accommodate the entire string, the returned Height component is adjusted to a value that allows displaying the string with character wrap_ (MSDN) it won't necessarily be such a mess..if you can live with character wrap, of course!